# Render partial onclick in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Is it possible to render a partial when a link is clicked?

I have searched google and here but I can't find anything useable.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The following example uses jQuery, as you tagged it :

In your view file (the page that is actually displayed) :

```
<%= link_to "Display a new view", path_to_controller, :remote => true %>
```

In your controller action (path_to_controller), add a js response :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

And in the path_to_controller.js.erb (the js response file) :

```
$("#your-placeholder-id").prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render 'path/to/view') %>');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi thanks, The partial I want to load via AJAX is called like this <%= render :partial => "variant", :collection => product.items.visible.order("position ASC") %>

Comment: Is that possible to do like you have suggested?

Comment: Yes, you have to type it <%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "variant", :collection => product.items.visible.order("position ASC")) %>. Just don't forget the escape_javascript!